# GIMP Python, toggle all paths visible or invisible, how?

Tags: python, gimp

I'm trying to create a GIMP Python plug-in to toggle visibility of all paths in the image on or off. This is to more easily process images with lots of paths (>100+) instead of endless clicking in the paths dialog.

The [GIMP Python documentation](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/) is not very helpful and I could only find the function set_component_visible. But when I try `img.set_component_visible(v, False)` or `img.set_component_visible(v, 0)` is gives this error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here is the code I have got so far:

```
from gimpfu import *
import os

def select_paths_visible(img, layer, tog, apl, wc):

    # iterate all paths (internally called "vectors")
    for v in img.vectors:
        img.set_component_visible(v, 0) # <== TypeError on this line

# tell gimp about our plugin
register(
    "python_fu_select_paths_visible",
    "Toggle paths visible",
    "Toggle paths visible",
    "BdR",
    "BdR",
    "2017",
    "<Image>/Tools/Toggle paths visible", # menu path
    "",
    [
        (PF_RADIO, "p1", "Toggle paths:", 1, (("Invisible", 0), ("Visible", 1))),
        (PF_RADIO, "p2", "Apply to paths:", 1, (("All", 0), ("With name", 1))),
        (PF_TEXT, "p3", "Pathname contains:", "test")
    ],
    [],
    select_paths_visible
)

main()
```

My question is
1. should I use set_component_visible differently
2. is there a different function to toggle paths visibility on/off?
3. What is a good source for documentation on the GIMP Python functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
for v in image.vectors:
    v.visible = False
```

1. `set_component_visible()` is about RGB channels and not paths (it seems to be the equivalent of clicking he visibility of the RGB channels in the Channels dialog)
2. `gimp_vectors_set_visible()` or change the attribute of the vector directly as done above
3. The Procedure Browser (`Browse...` button in the Python-fu console) is quite efficient IMHO. In Python, the more often used calls have equivalents as object methods and attributes. Use `dir(object)` to list methods and attributes. You will find many things that have obvious equivalents as PDB functions. Attributes may be be R/W (as `visible` above) or just R/O (and should then be changed with a method or a PDB function).

If you need sample code, see these two scripts repositories: [general scripts](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) and [paths-related scripts](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/)

PS: for you name criterion:

```
for v in image.vectors:
    if string in v.name:
        v.visible = False
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `Browse...` button to look for functions. Thanks for answering another GIMP Python related answer :) Seems like you're the expert